# How can I make the HTML5 canvas go fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fullscreen

I have seen dozens of tutorials on this, and it seems straight forward. All I want is to make my HTML5 canvas element go full-screen (as in total full-screen, taking up the whole monitor).

Here's my HTML:

```
<p><canvas id="screen" width="800" height="500"
    style="background: #FFFFFF; border: 5px solid black;" role="img">
        Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas></p>

<p><a href="javascript:goFullScreen();">Go Fullscreen</a></p>
```

Here's my Javascript (in its own .js file):

```
function goFullScreen(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
    if(canvas.requestFullScreen)
        canvas.requestFullScreen();
    else if(canvas.webkitRequestFullScreen)
        canvas.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    else if(canvas.mozRequestFullScreen)
        canvas.mozRequestFullScreen();
}
```

I tested the function; it gets called and one of the three ifs (namely, since I'm using Firefox, mozRequestFullScreen) gets called. My browser opens it up on every demo that I've tested, but not in my own code.

What's the missing variable? I must have Googled literally every link that mentions this, and still nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Well what's different about your own code? Does your canvas have a different `id`? Are you sure one of the `if` statements are being entered?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem. This does not work:

```
<p><a href="javascript:goFullScreen();">Go Fullscreen</a></p>
```

This DOES work:

```
<p><button onclick="goFullScreen();">Go Fullscreen</button></p>
```

Yeah... 3 hours later.

Comment: Well your first one *should* work, but isn't suggested/preferred

Comment: Wow. This is interesting. `javascript:something()` works differently depending on how you define the function: http://jsfiddle.net/WntTv/

Comment: If it's defined as `function something() {}` you get a ReferenceError. But if it's defined as `something = function() {}` the href handler can see it.

Comment: I found an explanation why my jsFiddle example works like that. By default jsFiddle wraps all JavaScript in a `window.onload = function() {}`. And obviously functions defined inside of another function are not visible in the global scope.

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev Reference error is thrown because of hoisting. See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Comment: @OmegaExtern As already explained above, it's because of the scope and not because of hoisting. Compare to the previous example: http://jsfiddle.net/zz8498o6/